# Fast access to the arbitrary page

Tags: feature-request

I would like to access the page `10000`:

[image]

but it looks like there is no fast access feature available.

Ideally, I could just enter the page number. Alternatively, increasing number of entries per page could speed up the search for the specific page.

Is such feature planned?

Comment: Kind request for Down-voter. Please, help me to understand: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: *Why* would you like to access page 10,000? Presumably you would need to go through the first 9,999 pages in order to know whether page 10,000 contains anything useful for you. What *real* use-case justifies this feature?

Comment: Downvotes indicate disagreement with your proposed feature.

Comment: @meagar Thank you kindly for your comments! I would like to have a freedom to search from the arbitrary page and not being forced to go through the previous  ones.

Comment: That's just a reiteration of your feature request with "I want" in front of it, that's not a strong justification for this feature. I'm asking what use you have for quickly navigating to the 10,000 page of results? What benefit does anybody derive from being able to quickly jump to an arbitrary page number, with no idea what they'll find on that page, and no idea what results they're skipping over by not checking the preceding pages?

Comment: @meagar It's useful if you're, for example, trying to binary search for a post based on some kind of criteria that normal search doesn't work for (and you don't want to break out SEDE). Those use cases are covered by changing the URL, of course.

Comment: @meagar  Let me try to answer how I came up with the request. Once the answers are arranged according to `newest` or `unanswered` category I would like to skip first few years and try to answer older questions.  I am not interested in a few first years.

Comment: @sg7 from the sounds of it you can do a search to only  include posts created within a certain time period eg: "created:..2y" will only include posts created more than 2 years ago.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for your helpful comment. Also, as Undo stated, the requested feature would be useful for all non typical searches.

Answer (score 7):

As a work around, after you select a page from the nav at the bottom, the URL will say something like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest
```

You can edit the URL to goto the desired page.  Not super convenient, but better than loading several thousand pages one at a time.